# Exporting items from a mailbox with EWS and SOAP

Tags: c#, soap, exchangewebservices

I need to export mail from a mailbox in our O365 tenant to a local disk. I've followed the Microsoft guidance for setting up an application in Azure AD so I can use OAuth to authenticate with EWS and this all seems to work fine. I understand I should be able to use a SOAP request to initiate an ExportItems request which contains the IDs of the items I want to export. This should then (according to the documentation) respond with an XML document that contains the bytes of the items requested in base64 which I can then write to files, however my SOAP request always returns a 500 error from Exchange Online and this is proving difficult to troubleshoot as I don't have any diagnostic output as to what is causing the error. The code for my proof-of-concept app so far is:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Xml;
using Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data;
using Microsoft.Identity.Client;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApp3
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static async System.Threading.Tasks.Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            const string ewsURL = "https://outlook.office365.com/ews/exchange.asmx";
            const string clientID = "d07b....";
            const string clientSecret = "MX....";
            const string tenantID = "38....";
            const string exportRoot = @"C:\_Export";

            var cca = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(clientID).WithClientSecret(clientSecret).WithTenantId(tenantID).Build();
            var ewsScopes = new string[] { "https://outlook.office365.com/.default" };
            var authResult = await cca.AcquireTokenForClient(ewsScopes).ExecuteAsync();

            var ewsClient = new ExchangeService();
            ewsClient.Url = new Uri(ewsURL);
            ewsClient.Credentials = new OAuthCredentials(authResult.AccessToken);

            ewsClient.ImpersonatedUserId = new ImpersonatedUserId(ConnectingIdType.SmtpAddress, "mailbox@contoso.com");
            ewsClient.HttpHeaders.Add("X-AnchorMailbox", "mailbox@contoso.com");
            ewsClient.TraceEnabled = true;
            var items = ewsClient.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, new ItemView(int.MaxValue));
            foreach(var item in items)
            {
                string exportPath = $"{exportRoot}\\{item.Id}.eml";
                HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(ewsClient.Url);
                request.Method = "POST";
                request.ContentType = "text/xml";
                request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
                
                request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + authResult.AccessToken);
                request.Headers.Add("X-AnchorMailbox", "mailbox@contoso.com");
                XmlDocument soapEnvelope = new XmlDocument();

                string envelope = File.ReadAllText("baseexportitemxml.txt");
                envelope = envelope.Replace("{0}", item.Id.ToString());

                soapEnvelope.LoadXml(envelope);
                byte[] soapBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(soapEnvelope.OuterXml);
                request.ContentLength  = soapBytes.Length;

                using(Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
                {
                    requestStream.Write(soapBytes, 0, soapBytes.Length);
                }

                using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse()) //500 internal server error here
                {
                    using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
                    {
                        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
                        {
                            string responseXML = reader.ReadToEnd();
                            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
                            doc.LoadXml(responseXML);
                            XmlNodeList mimeContentNodes = doc.GetElementsByTagName("m:Data");
                            string mimeContent = mimeContentNodes[0].InnerText;
                            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(exportPath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
                            {
                                byte[] contentBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(mimeContent);
                                fs.Write(contentBytes, 0, contentBytes.Length);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Process complete");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

The contents of the text file containing the XML for the SOAP request is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
      xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
      xmlns:t="https://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types"
      xmlns:m="https://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages">
  <soap:Header>
    <t:RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2013_SP1" />
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    <m:ExportItems>
      <m:ItemIds>
        <t:ItemId Id="{0}"/>
      </m:ItemIds>
    </m:ExportItems>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

The {0} placeholder is replaced in code with the ID of the item currently being processed.

I know the issue isn't authentication as if I comment out the line adding the token to the request headers I get the expected 401 error, so I think the issue is with the XML that is being sent to EWS, however I've copied this from a Microsoft article describing how to do this and only changed it so the ID isn't hard-coded in the file.

I'd be grateful for any advice on things I can try or pointers on where I am or might be going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your goal is to export the mime content of a Message (eg produce an EML file that will open in Outlook) then ExportItems isn't the correct thing to use. What ExportItems doesn't is produce an Opaque stream that can really only be used with the uploadItems operation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/web-service-reference/uploaditems-operation.

For a Mime export use the code in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/how-to-export-items-by-using-ews-in-exchange#use-the-mime-stream-to-export-into-common-file-formats

The problem with your request is a Schema error they ran a script a while ago that updated the EWS documentation incorrectly by changing the schema from xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ to xmlns:t="https://schemas.microsoft.com/ which is incorrect (as this is just a schema value) so your request should be

```html
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
      xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
      xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types"
      xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages">
  <soap:Header>
    <t:RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2016"/>
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    <m:ExportItems>
      <m:ItemIds>
        <t:ItemId Id="{0}"/>
      </m:ItemIds>
    </m:ExportItems>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```